# mvc rebuild strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

is there any way to re-build a strongly typed view when the model class has new fields added?

At present I have not modified the initial generated view so deleting and re-creating is not a problem.

When I start to customize it to my liking I will lose all changes and I was wondering if there was a good way to manage this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. When you update your model, you simply update your view to use any new fields / properties. Your views aren't tied to any specific version of your models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC offers two types of scaffolding, each with its own advantages:

The first kind of scaffolding is design-time scaffolding, which is done through the Add View dialog and T4 templates. The advantage of this is that the code is entirely generated and you can completely customize it. The disadvantage is that if you change your model you have to regenerate your view (by deleting it and adding back a new one).

The second kind of scaffolding is runtime scaffolding, which is done through the `Html.EditorFor()` and `Html.DisplayFor()` methods in your view. The advantage of this is that if your model changes then the scaffolding will be automatically generated at runtime. The disadvantage is that you cannot directly customize the rendering. You *can*, however, give this scaffolding many hints using DataAnnotations attributes such as `[DisplayText]`, `[UIHint]`, and so forth, so it is quite flexible - but it is not nearly as flexible as being able to 100% customize the rendering.

To customize the rendering of runtime scaffolding (editor templates and display templates) you can find more info on [Brad Wilson's blog series](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

Comment: when you say re-generate you view do you mean delete the file and re-create it or is there another way to re-generate? Cheers

Comment: @foz I meant delete and re-create. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You can make templates for the runtime-scafolding too! Tutorial on it here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: @alx yes thanks for the reminder! I was going to put in a link to Brad's blog and then I forgot :) I updated my answer with the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add code to your view to reflect any changes in the model.
Default scafolding is there just to give you something.

One thing you might want to look at is t4 templates using wich mvc tooling  generates your default views. google for it there are examples of how you can copy those to your project and modify to have mvc generate views you want instead of default ones.